# Show Matrix Aggregate column together in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008

In SSRS i am creating matrix report and in that i want to aggregate column together not 1 by 1 as mention below.

***Want to show***

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjnmQ.png)
**How it showing**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfCvz.png)
Thanks,
Santosh.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get the matrix to work the way you want.

What you can do is duplicate your current matrix then remove the Rank group from the first one.

Position the second matrix right next to the first.

Remove the City column but do not delete groups from the second table.

Remove the monthly total column from the second table.

You now have two matrixes (matrii?) next ot each other with the first one with the city and monthly totals and the second with just the rank. Since you didn't remove any grouping, the Cities should align.

Make sure the Location Top values match to align the tables so all the rows match up. I usually use round(ish) numbers (.5", .25", .125") when positioning objects to avoid alignment issues.